# if - else if not working

Tags: android, if-statement

I don't get why this last if-else if is not working.

I am trying to create event when 2 checkBoxes are checked at the same time for a project (quiz application).

I have put a log.v in the listeners to see if the listenCheck is working - and it does. It increments when i check the first two checkboxes(q7R1, q7R2) by one and decrements by two if i check the other two (q7R3,q7R4)

Thank you

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
    int listenCheck = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
        final Button button = findViewById(R.id.sub);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });

        q7R1 = findViewById(R.id.q7checkBox1);
        q7R2 = findViewById(R.id.q7checkBox2);
        q7R3 = findViewById(R.id.q7checkBox3);
        q7R4 = findViewById(R.id.q7checkBox4);


        q7Img = findViewById(R.id.imgQ7);
        q7R1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton1, boolean b) {
                if (q7R1.isChecked()) {
                    listenCheck += 1;
                    Log.v("Main2Activity", "listenchk" + listenCheck);
                }

            }
        });

        q7R2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton2, boolean b) {

                if (q7R2.isChecked()) {
                    listenCheck += 1;
                    Log.v("Main2Activity", "listenchk" + listenCheck);
                }
            }
        });

        q7R3.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton3, boolean b) {
                if (q7R3.isChecked()) {
                    listenCheck -= 2;
                    Log.v("Main2Activity", "listenchk" + listenCheck);
                }
            }
        });

        q7R4.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton4, boolean b) {
                if (q7R4.isChecked()) {
                    listenCheck -= 2;
                    Log.v("Main2Activity", "listenchk" + listenCheck);
                }
            }
        });

        correctState = (ContextCompat.getColorStateList(getApplicationContext(), R.color.radionbuttonstate));
        wrongState = (ContextCompat.getColorStateList(getApplicationContext(), R.color.radiobuttonwrong));
        checkAnswers();
    }

    public void q7Check2() {

        if (listenCheck == 2) {
            score = score + (100 / 8);
            q7R1.setTextColor(correctState);
            q7R2.setTextColor(correctState);
            q7Img.setImageResource(R.drawable.ddvspan);
        } else if (listenCheck < 0) {
            q7R3.setTextColor(wrongState);
            q7R4.setTextColor(wrongState);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getResources().getString(R.string.correct7), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        Log.v("Main2Activity", "listenchk" + listenCheck);
    }

    public void checkAnswers() {
        q1Check();
        q2Check();
        q3Check();
        q4Check();
        q5Check();
        q6Check();
        q7Check2();
        q8Check();
    }
}
```

Comment: You only call `checkAnswers()` once in `onCreate()` - `listenCheck` will always be zero at this point? Surely you should check answers on a "Submit" button, or something similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In every onCheckedChanged() method just call q7Check2() method

```
public void q7Check2() {

    if (q7R1.isChecked() && q7R2.isChecked()) {
        score = score + (100 / 8);
        q7R1.setTextColor(correctState);
        q7R2.setTextColor(correctState);
        q7Img.setImageResource(R.drawable.ddvspan);
    } else if (q7R3.isChecked() && q7R4.isChecked()) {
        q7R3.setTextColor(wrongState);
        q7R4.setTextColor(wrongState);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getResources().getString(R.string.correct7), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```